# Restricting a point to an arc on a circle's circumference

Tags: math, geometry

This question is a bit specific. Assume for simplicity that I have a unit circle, i.e. a circle centered on the origin (0,0) with radius 1. On this circle I have three points: A, B, and C. Assume that B and C are fixed, and that A can be moved along the circle's circumference.

**Question**: What conditions can I check efficiently to ensure that A is not moved outside the arc between B and C originally containing it?

As a point of clarification: I do not just wish to detect whether the point is on this arc or not (i.e., get a boolean), but to have a quantifiable measure (for example, of distance) so I can prevent it from being moved outside. You can imagine my setup like this, restricting point A to the red arc:

[image]

Here are some ideas I have pondered so far, but none were successful:

- Limit the angle alpha of A = [cos(alpha),sin(alpha)] to the origin between the angles beta and gamma of B=[cos(beta),sin(beta)] and C=[cos(gamma),sin(gamma)], where alpha, beta, and gamma are angles in radians. Unfortunately, this naive case only works in scenario (a) above. If the arc to which A is restricted crosses the (in my case, western) discontinuity from +pi/-pi, a naive upper and lower bound won't do.
- Calculate the length of the arcs between A-to-B and A-to-C, then ensure that as A is moved this sum does not change. Unfortunately, I have only found [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/830413/calculating-the-arc-length-of-a-circle-segment) to calculate the arcs between two points, and it always calculates the shorter arc. In scenario (c), however, the correct arc A-to-B is the larger one.

Comment: Wrong forum, this would belong on math.stackexchange :) I dont understand your problem either, try to really point down what you are after. You have two points B and C, that are fixed. What so you want to do with A? Is it given, or are you trying to calculate a valid A, i dont get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any two points on a circle, in your case `B` and `C`, there are of course two possible arcs. We use `A` to select between the two options. You say you want to prevent a point, say `D`, from moving outside this arc. I'm interpreting this to mean that we want a function which, if `D` lies on the arc defined by `BC` and `A`, returns `D`, otherwise it returns `B` or `C`, depending on which is nearer to `D`.

We can define the following function to implement this scheme:

```
def contstrainPoint(A, B, C, D)
  M = midpoint(B, C)
  If dot(MA, MD) >= 0 
    return D
  else if(dot(MB, MD) >= 0 
    return B
  else
    return C
```

Where `M` is the midpoint of the chord `BC` and `dot` is the dot product function.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take the cross product (**A**-**B**)x(**A**-**C**). This will have one non-zero component, normal to the plane. That component will vary smoothly, positive when **A** is on one arc, negative when it is on the other, and zero when it crosses **B** or **C**.